# How to use laravel Paginate and skip(1)

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, skip

**Hello.**

I currently work on creating a site that draws forum posts out onto a separate page where i use them as blog entries. In order to make it work as i want, i first ->get() the newest post for the top, main, blog entry, and then i foreach the others underneath it with masonry style like this : www.hockeyforat.se/laravel

This means that i do have this set up:

```
$post = Post::whereNewTopic(true)
            ->whereHas('Topic', function($q){$q->whereForumId(13);})
            ->orderBy('pid', 'DESC')
            ->first();
    $vars['p'] = $post;
```

And this obviously is meant to drag out the newest post and put it on top, so that works great, but then comes the other part where i have to skip the first post (as it is already on the page per above code). I used this to do that:

```
$posts = Post::whereNewTopic(true)
        ->whereHas('Topic', function($q){$q->whereForumId(13);})
        ->orderBy('pid', 'DESC')
        ->skip(1)
        ->take(100000)
        ->get();
    $vars['posts'] = $posts;
```

And this worked supremely too. But when i wanted to paginate it, i had some issues.. For some reason my **->paginate(6)** ignores the -**>skip(1)**. Anyone knows how to get around this? Example is here again : www.hockeyforat.se/laravel and I'll also add a picture below. As you can see, without skipping the first, I will get the same post in a row due to the first one being drawn out with $post here above.

```
$posts = Post::whereNewTopic(true)
            ->whereHas('Topic', function($q){$q->whereForumId(13);})
            ->orderBy('pid', 'DESC')
            **->skip(1)**
            ->take(100000)
            **->paginate(6);**
    $vars['posts'] = $posts;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIfi9.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldnt get the skip part to work with paginate as intended but it was solved by saying "Do not paginate whatever post id (pid) that is in $post.

```
$post = Post::whereNewTopic(true)
        ->whereHas('Topic', function($q){$q->whereForumId(13);})
        ->orderBy('pid', 'DESC')
        ->first();
$vars['p'] = $post;


$posts = Post::whereNewTopic(true)
            ->whereHas('Topic', function($q){$q->whereForumId(13);})
            ->where('pid', '<>', $post->pid)
            ->orderBy('pid', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(6);
$vars['posts'] = $posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

2 Ways:

- first: only use `->paginate(6)` without skip and take and render the 
  pagination numbers with `echo $users->render();`
- second: don't use    `->paginate(6)`, use `->take($take)` and
  `->skip($page * $take)`    meant in your case : `->take(6)` and
  `->skip($page * 6)`. `$page`    must be a part of your request and
  start with 0 (zero).

Comment: Got all working until it was time to render, so we started poking other ways and it was solved by the solution added to this question. Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

**It will 100%.** Go to AppserviceProvider and write this code for pagination in boot method. **You can use skip and take with pagination by this way.**

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

  Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
```

You need to write code in the controller.

```
if (isset($request->page))
   $request->request->remove('page');

$order = Order::where('status',1); 
$order_ = $order;
$order_count = $order_->count();
$order = $order->offset($received_record)->take($per_page)
-orderBy('orders.updated_at','ASC')->get();
$order =  collect($order)->paginate($per_page,$order_count);
```

Comment: Heads, up - as you can see, this is a very old post. And as such, it's not the current framework. So are you certain this works for Laravel 5.4?

Comment: It'll work for laravel 6.18 to onward 9.36

Comment: So, that is a no. Which is why this reply should not have been put here. You're necromancing for points, putting code from a newer framework into a question that was made 8 years ago when those did not even exist.